# URL redirection added to .htaccess

Tags: apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

Can anyone help me with adding the redirect rules to my .htaccess? I want to redirect websites visitors based on the URL they enter. For example:

1. If a visitor enters URL **without www** to be redirected to my root (index.php)
2. If a visitor enters URL, but **with the WWW** to be redirected to http://domain.com/home/index.html

---

**Edit**: From your description above and your comment below, it sounds like you want requests to be redirected like this:

```
www.domain.com             -> domain.com/home/index.html
www.domain.com/about.php   -> domain.com/home/index.html
domain.com                 -> domain.com/index.php
domain.com/home/index.html -> domain.com/index.php
domain.com/news.php?id=5   -> domain.com/index.php
```

If not, please replace this edit with some corrected examples.

Comment: You want every request to be redirected to either index.php or index.html?  Do you mean a 301 redirect or do you mean a translation?

Comment: I would like every request to be redirected. If user enters http://domain.com he would be redirected to http://domain.com. If users enters http://www.domain.com he would be redirected to http://domain.com/home/index.html. And I mean 301 redirect.

Comment: So I put this code to my .htaccess file?

Comment: No, I'm trying to understand the behavior you want.  The left shows where the browser attempts to go, and the right is where the user would be redirected.  That can't be right, but it's what you've indicated.  Please clarify what you want.

Comment: OK, here are the directions I want:

www.domain.com             -> domain.com/home/index.html
domain.com                 -> domain.com (index.php - only index in root!)

Answer (score 1):

Try these rules:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^www\.
RewriteRule ^ http://example.com/home/index.html [R=301,L]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www\.
RewriteRule ^ http://example.com/index.php [R=301,L]
```

But note that if you’re redirecting to the same host (like the first rule probably does), you will get an infinite recursion. So you might want to delimit the first rule by excluding `/home/index.html`:

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^www\.
RewriteRule !^home/index\.html$ http://example.com/home/index.html [R=301,L]
```

Comment: Gumbo thank you for your answer but if I add this lines to my .htaccess file, all my visitors are redirected to http://example.com/home/index.html directory.

I would like to redirect those who enters url without www part to root directory like example.com

http://www.example.com --> http://example.com/home/index.html

and

http://example.com --> http://example.com (where index.php is)

Comment: Ok, problem solved. All I needed was

RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www\.
RewriteRule ^ http://example.com/home [R=301,L]

Thank you!!!!